# How can I count the appearance # of a word (not total appearances)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my desired output:

[image]

The first time the word "orange" is found, it is recorded that is the **first** appearance in column B.

The second time the word "orange" is found, it is recorded that is the **second** appearance in column B.

And so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IF and COUNTIF:

```
=IF(A2="orange",COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),"")
```

Put that in B2 and copy/drag down the dataset

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! I understand, so the dynamically referenced cell changes as it is dragged down, which means it is counting from row A2 to the current row. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
=IF(A2="orange",MAX(B$1:B1)+1,"")
```

[image]